# Как просто обновить див без load каждый секунд?

Tags: javascript

Как просто обновить див без load каждый секунд?

Например

```
$("#time").html("<?php echo date("H:i:s"); ?>")
```

**UPDATE**

У меня сейчас поставлен такой код

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  $("#time").html(""+date.toLocaleTimeString()+"")
}, 1000);
var date = new Date();
$("#time").html(""+date.toLocaleTimeString()+"")
});
```

Если я поставлю php код например так то не обновляется почему?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  $("#time").html("<?php echo date("H:i:s"); ?>")
}, 1000);
var date = new Date();
$("#time").html("<?php echo date("H:i:s"); ?>")
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать `setInterval`.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("#time").html(formatDate(new Date()));
}, 1000);

function formatDate(date) {
  var hour = "0" + date.getHours(),
      minute = "0" + date.getMinutes(),
      second = "0" + date.getSeconds();
  return [hour.slice(-2), minute.slice(-2), second.slice(-2)].join(":");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

---

> Если я поставлю php код например так то не обновляется почему?
>   ...
>   `$("#time").html("<?php echo date("H:i:s"); ?>")`

PHP выполняается, потом JavaScript выполняется. После того, что PHP выполняется, JavaScript выглядит так (например):

```
$("#time").html("15:16:10")
```

и будет показать эту строку `15:16:10` каждую секунду. Поэтому, надо обновить время в JavaScript.

Comment: Спасибо я понял

Answer (score 2):

[По таймеру](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) вызывайте JS функцию, которая обновит время. [Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/e8szcxvt/).

```js
var $el = $('#timer');

var second = function(){
    var D = new Date();
    $el.html(
        '' +D.getHours()
        +':'+D.getMinutes()
        +':'+D.getSeconds()
    );
};

window.setInterval( second, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

**Обновление**

Наверное, вы заметите, что время щелкает не совсем равномерно – иногда может "задуматься", а потом проскочить секунду. Это связано с тем, что `setInterval()` работает не точно. И если вы хотите более плавное/точное время, сделайте вызов ф-ии раз 10–50 в секунду. Тогда ошибка будет не так заметна.

Comment: Sergiks Спасибо!